# Retrieve my Spotify playlist id from my Android app

Tags: android, spotify, playlist

I'm trying to retrieve the id of my playlists in Spotify so that I can show the content (playlists name, tracks, etc.) in a ListView in my Android app. I can't find a way to get that data.

I copied the Android Quick Start source code given by Spotify. Everything works clean as long as I know the playlist ID ("spotify:playlist:5smL9JMG88uvAabko1c5P0"). But what about if I don't know it and I want to get it from Spotify (so, for example, if I have many playlists in my account I can decide in my app which one to play)? Is there a get method for Android?
I don't show any code because it's the same provided by Spotify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not know the playlist id of the playlist you can use the following Spotify Web API Endpoint to get all of the users playlists : [Get List Users Playlists](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/playlists/get-list-users-playlists/)

There are [libraries](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/libraries/) for the Spotify Web API, therefore you do not need to implement this by yourself if you do not want to.

If you choose the [kaaes/spotify-web-api-android](https://github.com/kaaes/spotify-web-api-android) library, the code could be something like this:

```
SpotifyApi api = new SpotifyApi();
api.setAccessToken("yourAccessToken");
SpotifyService spotify = api.getService();

spotify.getMyPlaylists(new SpotifyCallback<Pager<PlaylistSimple>>() {
    @Override
    public void failure(SpotifyError spotifyError) {
        // handle error
    }

    @Override
    public void success(Pager<PlaylistSimple> playlistSimplePager, Response response) {
        // do something
        // for example
        for(PlaylistSimple playlistSimple: playlistSimplePager.items) {
            Log.d("playlist:", playlistSimple.name);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! It looks very good. I'm just having hard time to get the access token. As soon as I make it I'll give it a try.

Comment: To obtain the access token you can use a library, too. [Android SDK Authentication Guide](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/android/guides/android-authentication/#single-sign-on-with-spotify-client-and-a-webview-fallback) If this doesn't help open another question and provide some details regarding the authentication question/issue.

Comment: I tried everything I could imagine but with no success. So I opened a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55671086/i-cant-retrieve-an-access-token-from-spotify-for-my-app